# How to implement try and catch in my calculator to prevent errors?

Tags: javascript, calculator

If my input is 6++ I'm getting 6++ as the output, rather I want an 'err' in the output. How can I implement try and catch in my code to throw the error? ex inputs: 6++ output: err, input: 5+-3 output: err, etc.

Here's my code:

```js
let string = "";
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
Array.from(buttons).forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML == '=') {
      string = eval(string);
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'C') {
      string = " ";
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else {
      console.log(e.target)
      string = string + e.target.innerHTML;
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Why should `5 + -3` lead to an `err`?

Comment: Don't use `eval` to evaluate mathematical formulas.

Comment: By 5+-3 I mean putting that into your calculator shouldn't work. I didn't say 5+(-3). 
I meant for example 86//*2 should throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put `try` and `catch` around the code that calls `eval()`.

Note that `5+-3` is perfectly fine in JavaScript, it's equivalent to `5-3`, so you won't get an error for that.

```js
let string = "";
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
Array.from(buttons).forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.innerHTML == '=') {
      try {
        string = eval(string);
        document.querySelector('input').value = string;
      } catch (e) {
        document.querySelector('input').value = "error: " + e;
      }
    } else if (e.target.innerHTML == 'C') {
      string = " ";
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    } else {
      console.log(e.target)
      string = string + e.target.innerHTML;
      document.querySelector('input').value = string;
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: please try this expression 86//*2.

Comment: That's clearly invalid. It's not the same as `5+-3` because `-` serves two functions in JavaScript: it's the subtraction operator and it's also the negative prefix. So `5+-3` is treated as `5+(-3)`

Comment: BTW, `1/*2*/+3` is also valid because `/* ... */` is a comment.